# How to return my last count id queryBuilder

Tags: symfony, query-builder

Hi i'm new on symfony be indulgent plz, here's my code

```
public function countTicket()
{
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->innerJoin('t.visitors', 'v')
        ->Select("count(v.id)")
        ->where('t.visitDate IS NOT NULL')
        ->groupBy('t.visitDate')

    ;

    return $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getScalarResult();
}
```

When i dump countTicket() it returns all my Id's entity, group in all visitDate which is normal but i just want to return the count (v.id) from the last visitDate i submit and i don't know how to do that.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `getSingleScalarResult()` instead of `getScalarResult()`, and limit your query to fetch the last result only, like this:

```
public function countTicket()
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->innerJoin('t.visitors', 'v')
        ->select('count(v.id)')
        ->where('t.visitDate IS NOT NULL')
        ->orderBy('t.visitDate', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('t.visitDate')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, so  i have tried with getSingleScalarResult() but i have an error it says "The query returned multiple rows. Change the query or use a different result function like getScalarResult()."

Comment: @b.w I just updated the code. If you want only the last record, you should limit the query, then `getSingleScalarResult()` is going to work.

Comment: I don't know where i did wrong but it returns the first record.

Comment: You should probably order by date, desc.